# Novel where a girl falls in love with a gypsy and investigates a murder

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this as a free novel on a plane flight. A girl falls in love with a young gypsy who can do magic (shape-change, enter her dreams). There's a lawyer trying to cheat the gypsy’s mother (who is weird and witchy), a couple of nice cops, a gypsy funeral where they push a Cadillac into the ocean, and the gypsy’s sister or cousin is drunk and slutty. It's modern urban fantasy, post 2010 I think.

Comment: I think this might be the Nostradamus Prophecies by Mario Reading. It has elements of similarity, but I can't find any useful quotes at the moment.